# Check the SQL Server database & table size

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows

How can one check the SQL Server database and table size (in MB) using C#?

Comment: Duplicate of [Determine SQL Server Database Size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/176379/determine-sql-server-database-size), [SQL Server 2008: How to query all databases sizes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5945360/sql-server-2008-how-to-query-all-databases-sizes) and some others. Please use the search first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at the `sp_spaceused` stored procedure?
Just execute it with `DBName.Tablename`.

Here is the [MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188776.aspx)